# Understanding log probabilities of actions in the PPO objective

Tags: python, objective-functions, implementation, proximal-policy-optimization

I'm trying to implement the Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) algorithm ([code here](https://github.com/ChintanTrivedi/rl-bot-football/blob/master/train.py)), but I am confused about certain concepts.

1. What is the correct way to implement log probability of a policy (denoted by $\pi_\theta$ below)?
   $$
   L^{C P I}(\theta)=\hat{\mathbb{E}}_{t}\left[\frac{\pi_{\theta}\left(a_{t} | s_{t}\right)}{\pi_{\theta_{\text {old }}}\left(a_{t} | s_{t}\right)} \hat{A}_{t}\right]=\hat{\mathbb{E}}_{t}\left[r_{t}(\theta) \hat{A}_{t}\right]
   $$
   Let's say my old network policy output is `oldpolicy_probs=[0.1,0.2,0.6,0.1]` and new network policy output is `newpolicy_probs=[0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2]`.

   Do I take the log of this directly, or should I first multiply these with the true label `y_true = [0,0,1,0]` as implemented [here](https://github.com/LuEE-C/PPO-Keras/blob/3bd92268d45ac4f0709f926f24392ed99252daac/Main.py#L45)?
2. `ratio = np.mean(np.exp(np.log(newpolicy_probs + 1e-10) - K.log(oldpolicy_probs + 1e-10))*advantage)`

   Once I have the ratio and I multiply it with an advantage, why do we take the mean over all actions? I suspect it might be because we are taking estimate $\hat{\mathbb{E}_t}$ but conceptually I don't understand what this gives us. Is my implementation above correct?

Comment: I have the same question. In this scenario, you have discrete actions right? How were you able to handle this?

Comment: @AhmedAlagha Please see the implementation of ppo loss [here on github](https://github.com/ChintanTrivedi/rl-bot-football/blob/master/train.py#L63).